How to stop animation with kivy -python
I'm using kivy to develop a small project. Currently, I use the animation utility to animate Widgets (change size). Everything works great so far, but I have no idea how I am supposed to stop animations and continue other code lines.
It is code that I try
class Animination:
    def __init__(self):
        self.anim_zoom_in = None
        self.anim_zoom_out = None
    def animate_zoom(self, target_widget):
        anim_zoom_in = Animation(width=dp(60), height=dp(80), duration=1)
        anim_zoom_out = Animation(width=dp(80), height=dp(100), duration=1)
        anim_zoom_in.bind(on_complete=lambda *x: anim_zoom_out.start(target_widget))
        anim_zoom_out.bind(on_complete=lambda *x: anim_zoom_in.start(target_widget))
        anim_zoom_in.start(target_widget)
    def stop_animation(self, target_widget):
        if self.anim_zoom_in:
            self.anim_zoom_in.unbind(on_complete=None)
            self.anim_zoom_in.cancel(target_widget)
        if self.anim_zoom_out:
            self.anim_zoom_out.unbind(on_complete=None)
            self.anim_zoom_out.cancel(target_widget)

I am trying to stop by calling stop_animating function.But it is still running.

The cancel() method will stop an Animation. Something else must be going on. Please post a [mcve].

Your animate_zoom() method does not set self.anim_zoom_in or self.anim_zoom_out. So those values are still None when stop_animation() is called.
